# PHP Sessions Not Saving for random users

Tags: php, .htaccess, session-cookies

I am currently running a project on PHP 5.6 as the project runs on old PHP code. I currently have an issue where random users are unable to retain their sessions.

For example users are logging in and their session is immediately being unset.

I have tried everything within my knowledge to fix the problem:
- Checked my configuration file calls session start
- Checked SSL isn’t causing session to unset
- Set all session unset commands with database functions to comments at the minute
- Checked htaccess files with no luck
- Double checked users are visiting http://www. Or http:// only (not one then the other)
- Checked that cookies are not being blocked by users browser
- Checked that Adblock plugins are not interfering.

I believe it may be my htaccess files that are causing the issue but I am not an expert in these, I have put my htaccess file code below

```
Options -Indexes

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ V2/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
</IfModule>

<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 90
   php_value max_input_time -1
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 64M
   php_value post_max_size 20M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path ".cagefs/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 400 /V2/404

ErrorDocument 401 /V2/404

ErrorDocument 403 /V2/404

ErrorDocument 404 /V2/404

ErrorDocument 500 /V2/404

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SpiderWeb [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|PNG|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 3 HOUR
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|php|html|zip)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=10800"
</FilesMatch>

# NEVER CACHE - notice the extra directives
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|cgi|pl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<files *.php>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Would anyone have any idea as to possible issues for this?

ERROR LOG FILE

```
    [04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/sitename/public_html/panel/_inc/db.inc.php on line 11
[04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/sitename/public_html/panel/_inc/db.inc.php on line 11
[04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(http://...@andromeda.shoutca.st:8619/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml&amp;page=1&amp;sid=1): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/sitename/public_html/V2/index.php on line 260
[04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http%3A%2F%2Fadmin%3ASrM%7BO%29-%29O0O8%40andromeda.shoutca.st%3A8619%2Fadmin.cgi%3Fmode%3Dviewxml%26page%3D1%26sid%3D1&quot; in /home/sitename/public_html/V2/index.php on line 260
[04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(http://...@andromeda.shoutca.st:8619/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml&amp;page=1&amp;sid=1): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/sitename/public_html/V2/index.php on line 260
[04-Feb-2020 21:43:43 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http%3A%2F%2Fadmin%3ASrM%7BO%29-%29O0O8%40andromeda.shoutca.st%3A8619%2Fadmin.cgi%3Fmode%3Dviewxml%26page%3D1%26sid%3D1&quot; in /home/sitename/public_html/V2/index.php on line 260
```

Don't believe simplexml_load_file error to be the problem as this is a shoutcast service. Currently having issues with my shoutcast host so waiting for those to be sorted (this wouldn't cause sessions to unset)

I know PHP are depreciating the MYSQL connect which is why the project is running on PHP 5.6

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you been checking your logs / used error reporting? Your question only contains  .htaccess code, not php or sessions. If this is php related, you need to post the code you're using for all this.

Comment: Hi @FunkFortyNiner I didn't put this in my code because it is definitely setting but is unsetting for no reason to random users, my login is linked to a config file which is linked to a class file, I've double checked all these, everything seems fine. I will double check my error log

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using very cheap multi-tenant hosting - diagnosing anything here will be very difficult. Your htaccess file shows your environment has very relaxed controls.

We cannot answer the question of why your sessions are failing, however there is nothing in the information you have presented to demonstrate the sessions failing. Your next steps are:

1) amend the code and logging such that you can track the behaviour - e.g. by dropping a random persistent cookie and logging both that and the the session id. You could also inject an environment var from PHP code about the state of the session back into Apache for logging.

2) Stop using the default handler - you have no visibility/control over how it is behaving. There are lots of others available (I suggest a MySQL based one) and add instrumentation there.